# Am I allowed to enter EU after leaving the country I have the Resident Permit for?

Tags: europe, tourist-visas, eu, finland, blue-card

I am a Non-EU citizen and I have a Residence permit specifically a blue card in Finland. Now my blue card is valid till June 2024. Now, I would be leaving Finland for good and would be moving to a Non-EU/EEA country. I will go through all the de-registration processes before leaving. My question is can I visit EU/EEA countries after that for short visits (lesser than 1-2 weeks) for the purpose of tourism till June 2024?

Comment: Beware, you may have to surrender your Blue Card as part of the deregistration procedure or it may be invalidated if the Finnish authorities know you are moving out of the EU (one tricky nuance is that you should be able to keep it to help you to the transition to another EU country). My advice would be to apply for a visa. It's a hassle and cost a bit of money but as a past resident, the risk of a refusal should be low.

Comment: @Relaxed I think this would depend on whether or not continuous employment is a condition for keeping the Finnish blue card? If you're allowed to be "unemployed", you could just not deregister without breaking the law.

Comment: @JonathanReez surely there's a law requiring those leaving the country to deregister promptly that would be broken by pursuing such a plan.

Comment: @phoog depends on how the law is written. My comment was trying to point out that it’s important to look at the nitty gritty details of Finnish law for a good answer.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think employment is the main issue here, not being a resident is. I know a few countries where you can remain a resident after losing your job and also some where there is no deregistration but I am yet to learn of a single country anywhere on earth where the two issues would be linked. We also know that deregistration is mandatory in Finland and the OP intends to go through with it (that's in the question, which is why I did not belabor this point) but you'll note I used the word "may" throughout and did not post an answer.

Comment: When you give up your residence permanently and leave the Schengen Area, you should **not** use the *residence permit card* later to reenter the Schengen Area. When the **Entry/Exit System (EES)** comes into effect, validity checks of the residence permits will be made on entry. If the card has been invalidated and your citizenship requires a visa, you may be refused entry.

Comment: We need more info. Can you give us a link to the deregistration process you will use so we can check what it entails?

Answer (score 2):

No, it will likely be canceled, either automatically or on the spot at the border :

---

The Finnish Migration service on both [FAQ](https://migri.fi/en/faq-residence-permits) and [RP Cancellation](https://migri.fi/en/cancellation-of-a-permit) pages has that to say :

> If you move permanently away from Finland, your residence permit will be cancelled.

> Your fixed-period or temporary residence permit will be cancelled if

> - you move from Finland permanently
> - you otherwise reside outside Finland for a permanent purpose for two years uninterrupted.

> An EU Blue Card will be cancelled if you have been unemployed for three months without interruption. You must always return the card when the permit is cancelled and the card is voided.

The important part is :

As you will likely not stay employed as a Blue Card holder, it will *automatically* cancel after 3 months of you leaving your job.

---

If you stay employed to your Finnish employer, while moving abroad, this might be different and then you would have your permit canceled after 2 years of **permanent residence** outside of Finland

I couldn't find a definition of residence from the Finnish authorities of what exactly is residence for such purposes, but the citizenship [definition](https://migri.fi/en/how-to-calculate-the-period-of-residence) is :

> Your continuous period of residence is interrupted if you leave Finland regularly for such long periods of time that you can be considered to reside the most of your time outside Finland.

> The following period of absence from Finland will not interrupt your continuous period of residence but **it will not be calculated as continuous residence time**:
>
> - a period of absence that lasts longer than six months but one year at maximum

This means that practically speaking, any absence longer than 6 months (usually more than 183 days), will count you as not-resident for the year and doing that for 2 years, you will have your permit cancelled.

---

Depending on circumstances, you might be able to apply to the migration service to prevent those cancellations :

> If you do not want your residence permit to be cancelled because you are living abroad, you should apply within two years of moving abroad to have the cancellation prevented. Apply by filling in the form [OLE_PER](https://migri.fi/documents/5202425/7005282/Hakemus+oleskeluluvan+peruuttamatta+j%C3%A4tt%C3%A4miseksi,+OLE_PER_en.pdf/9738e9b6-f52a-fffb-4b12-13682665970b/Hakemus+oleskeluluvan+peruuttamatta+j%C3%A4tt%C3%A4miseksi,+OLE_PER_en.pdf?t=1634038277348) in Finnish, Swedish or English.

But, it will imply that you will come back at some times which will not be the case if you move permanently

---

**TL;DR** Have your RP cancelled formally ([procedure](https://migri.fi/en/cancellation-of-a-permit)) and applying for a Schengen visa (if applicable) when you want to visit back is likely the preferred way in your situation.

If you decide not to, never use it again to enter the EU or you will be in a huge lot of trouble at the border (quite unlikely but still a possibility, when the [EES](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/smart-borders/entry-exit-system_en) will be rolled out you can be confident that you will have such issues) because the unemployment clause *(after 3 months, if that applies, the other clauses if it doesn't apply)* will likely have been triggered either automatically or directly at the border.

EDIT: It might also be nasty not to formally cancel your Blue Card :

> You must always return the card when the permit is cancelled and the card is voided.

Identity documents are always property of the issuing government, so, assuming you don't return your Blue Card, you may end up in trouble as it is required to do so (usually, that would be a fine, but I don't know for Finland exactly)

*All emphasis are mine*

Comment: Minor note: the fine for not returning your Schengen residence permit in Czech Republic is only $50 last I checked. It’s probably pretty small in Finland as well, though I’d still do it.

Comment: @JonathanReez How do I know my permit was received? I sent it back to the MOI but not sure if it was received or not.

Comment: How does one know they received the card and canceled one's stay?